# Wrapper/abstraction for encryption and decryption using OpenSSL

Tags: c, cryptography, aes, openssl

I am a beginner when it comes to cryptography and OpenSSL. I have written a short wrapper of some functions in OpenSSL as well as a test of this wrapper, copied below.

Specifically, this code is intended to be used as a means of encrypting and decrypting data using either RSA or AES. This code is also meant to abstract away the details of encryption and decryption.

I am especially concerned that I have used the OpenSSL library correctly. For example, in my function generate_rsa_keypair(), did I call RSA_new(), BN_new(), BN_set_word(), RSA_generate_key_ex(), PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey() correctly and with the appropriate arguments? Am I using the results correctly?

I would really appreciate any code reviews by experienced cryptography and OpenSSL developers. This code can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/waynemystir/crypto_wrapper).

```
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include "crypto_wrapper.h"

//#define PADDING RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
#define PADDING RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
//#define PADDING RSA_NO_PADDING

int generate_rsa_keypair(RSA **keypair,
    char **private_key,
    char **public_key,
    char *private_key_filepath,
    char *public_key_filepath) {

    RSA *kp = RSA_new();
    BIGNUM *exponent = BN_new();
    BN_set_word(exponent, RSA_F4);

    int res = RSA_generate_key_ex(kp, 2048, exponent, NULL);
    if (!res) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        RSA_free(kp);
        BN_clear_free(exponent);
        CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
        return -1;
    }

    // printf("kpkpkp:(%d)\n", RSA_size(kp));

    BIO *pri = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri, kp, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub, kp);

    size_t pri_len = BIO_pending(pri);
    size_t pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);

    char *pri_key = malloc(pri_len + 1);
    char *pub_key = malloc(pub_len + 1);

    BIO_read(pri, pri_key, pri_len);
    BIO_read(pub, pub_key, pub_len);

    pri_key[pri_len] = '\0';
    pub_key[pub_len] = '\0';

    if (private_key) {
        *private_key = malloc(pri_len + 1);
        strcpy(*private_key, pri_key);
    }

    if (public_key) {
        *public_key = malloc(pub_len + 1);
        strcpy(*public_key, pub_key);
    }

    if (private_key_filepath) {
        FILE *priv_file = fopen(private_key_filepath, "w+");
        if (priv_file) {
            fputs(pri_key, priv_file);
            fclose(priv_file);
        }
    }

    if (public_key_filepath) {
        FILE *publ_file = fopen(public_key_filepath, "w+");
        if (publ_file) {
            fputs(pub_key, publ_file);
            fclose(publ_file);
        }
    }

    if (keypair) *keypair = kp;
    else RSA_free(kp);
    BN_clear_free(exponent);
    BIO_free_all(pri);
    BIO_free_all(pub);
    free(pri_key);
    free(pub_key);
    CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();

    return 0;
}

char *read_file_to_str(char *filepath) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (f) {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        long fsize = ftell(f);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);  //same as rewind(f);
        char *str = malloc(fsize + 1);
        fread(str, fsize, 1, f);
        str[fsize] = 0;
        fclose(f);
        return str;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void load_public_key_from_filepath(RSA **public_key, char *filepath) {
    char *r = read_file_to_str(filepath);
    if (r) load_public_key_from_str(public_key, r);
    free(r);
}

void load_public_key_from_str(RSA **public_key, char *str) {
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)str, -1) ; // -1: assume string is null terminated
    BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL) ; // NO NL
    // Load the RSA key from the BIO
    RSA* rsa_pub_key = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(!rsa_pub_key)
        printf("ERROR: Could not load PUBLIC KEY! PEM_read_bio_RSA_pub_key FAILED: %s\n",
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

    if (public_key) *public_key = rsa_pub_key;
    BIO_free(bio);
    CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
}

void load_private_key_from_filepath(RSA **private_key, char *filepath) {
    char *r = read_file_to_str(filepath);
    if (r) load_private_key_from_str(private_key, r);
    free(r);
}

void load_private_key_from_str(RSA **private_key, char *str) {
    BIO *bio = BIO_new_mem_buf( (void*)str, -1 );
    //BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); // NO NL
    RSA* rsa_priv_key = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (!rsa_priv_key)
        printf("ERROR: Could not load PRIVATE KEY! PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey FAILED: %s\n",
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
    BIO_free( bio ) ;
    if (private_key) *private_key = rsa_priv_key;
    CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
}

void rsa_encrypt(RSA *public_key,
    const unsigned char* data,
    unsigned char *encrypted_data,
    int *result_len) {
    int rsa_len = RSA_size(public_key);
    int data_size = strlen((char*)data);
    memset(encrypted_data, '\0', rsa_len);
    *result_len = RSA_public_encrypt(data_size, (const unsigned char*)data, encrypted_data, public_key, PADDING);
    if (*result_len == -1)
        printf("ERROR: RSA_public_encrypt: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
}

void rsa_decrypt(RSA *private_key,
    const unsigned char* encrypted_data,
    unsigned char *decrypted_data,
    int *result_len) {
    int rsa_len = RSA_size(private_key) ; // That's how many bytes the decrypted data would be
    memset(decrypted_data, '\0', rsa_len);
    *result_len = RSA_private_decrypt(rsa_len, encrypted_data, decrypted_data, private_key, PADDING);
    if (*result_len == -1)
        printf("ERROR: RSA_private_decrypt: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
}

void handleErrors(void)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

int aes_encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext,
    unsigned char *key,
    unsigned char *iv,
    unsigned char *ciphertext) {

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int ciphertext_len;
    int plaintext_len = strlen((char*)plaintext);

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
    * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
    * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
    * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
    * is 128 bits */
    if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
    * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
    */
    if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
    * this stage.
    */
    if (1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}

int aes_decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext,
    int ciphertext_len,
    unsigned char *key,
    unsigned char *iv,
    unsigned char *plaintext) {

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
    * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
    * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
    * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
    * is 128 bits */
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
    * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
    */
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;

    /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
    * this stage.
    */
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

int generate_rsa_keypair(RSA **keypair,
    char **private_key,
    char **public_key,
    char *private_key_filepath,
    char *public_key_filepath);

void load_public_key_from_filepath(RSA **public_key, char *filepath);

void load_public_key_from_str(RSA **public_key, char *str);

void load_private_key_from_filepath(RSA **private_key, char *filepath);

void load_private_key_from_str(RSA **private_key, char *str);

void rsa_encrypt(RSA *pubic_key,
    const unsigned char *data,
    unsigned char *encrypted_data,
    int *result_len);

void rsa_decrypt(RSA *private_key,
    const unsigned char *encrypted_data,
    unsigned char *decrypted_data,
    int *result_len);

int aes_encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext,
    unsigned char *key,
    unsigned char *iv,
    unsigned char *ciphertext);

int aes_decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext,
    int ciphertext_len,
    unsigned char *key,
    unsigned char *iv,
    unsigned char *plaintext);
```

And this is the tester:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include "crypto_wrapper.h"

#define NUM_BYTES_AES_KEY 256
#define NUM_BYTES_AES_IV 128

int main() {
    printf("crypto_wrapper_test main 0\n");

    char *private_key_str = NULL;
    char *public_key_str = NULL;
    generate_rsa_keypair(NULL, &private_key_str, &public_key_str, NULL, NULL);

    // printf("security_test main 1 (%s)\n", public_key_str);
    // printf("security_test main 2 (%s)\n", private_key_str);

    unsigned char rsa_plaintext[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
    unsigned char rsa_encrypted_data[512];
    unsigned char rsa_decrypted_data[512];
    memset(rsa_encrypted_data, '\0', 512);
    memset(rsa_decrypted_data, '\0', 512);

    RSA *rsa_pub_key;
    load_public_key_from_str(&rsa_pub_key, public_key_str);
    int result_len = 0;
    rsa_encrypt(rsa_pub_key, rsa_plaintext, rsa_encrypted_data, &result_len);
    printf("rsa_encrypted:(%s)(%d)\n", rsa_encrypted_data, result_len);

    RSA *rsa_priv_key;
    load_private_key_from_str(&rsa_priv_key, private_key_str);
    rsa_decrypt(rsa_priv_key, (const unsigned char*)rsa_encrypted_data, rsa_decrypted_data, &result_len);
    printf("rsa_decrypted:(%s)(%d)\n", rsa_decrypted_data, result_len);

    unsigned char symmetric_key[NUM_BYTES_AES_KEY];
    unsigned char iv[NUM_BYTES_AES_IV];
    memset(symmetric_key, '\0', NUM_BYTES_AES_KEY);
    memset(iv, '\0', NUM_BYTES_AES_IV);

    if (!RAND_bytes(symmetric_key, sizeof(symmetric_key))) {
        printf("RAND_bytes failed for symmetric_key\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
    }

    if (!RAND_bytes(iv, sizeof(iv))) {
        printf("RAND_bytes failed for iv\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
    }

    printf("symmetric key:\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_BYTES_AES_KEY; j++)
        printf("(%02X)", symmetric_key[j]);
    printf("\niv:\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_BYTES_AES_IV; k++)
        printf("(%02X)", iv[k]);
    printf("\n");

    unsigned char aes_plaintext[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";
    unsigned char ciphertext[512];
    memset(ciphertext, '\0', 512);
    int ciphertext_len = aes_encrypt(aes_plaintext, symmetric_key, iv, ciphertext);

    printf("ciphertext (%s)\n(%d) (%lu) (%lu)\n",
        ciphertext,
        ciphertext_len,
        strlen((char*)ciphertext),
        sizeof(ciphertext));

    unsigned char aes_decryptedtext[512];
    memset(aes_decryptedtext, '\0', 512);
    int aes_plaintext_len = aes_decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, symmetric_key, iv, aes_decryptedtext);

    char substr_aes_decryptedtext[aes_plaintext_len+1];
    memcpy( substr_aes_decryptedtext, aes_decryptedtext, aes_plaintext_len);
    substr_aes_decryptedtext[aes_plaintext_len] = '\0';
    int first_index_aes_plaintext_null = 0;
    for (; first_index_aes_plaintext_null < 512; first_index_aes_plaintext_null++) {
        if (aes_decryptedtext[first_index_aes_plaintext_null] == '\0') break;
    }

    printf("aes_decrypt (%s) (%d) (%d)\n", substr_aes_decryptedtext, first_index_aes_plaintext_null, aes_plaintext_len);

    RSA_free(rsa_pub_key);
    RSA_free(rsa_priv_key);
    free(private_key_str);
    free(public_key_str);

    printf("\ncrypto_wrapper main 1\n");

    return 0;
}
```